# What are the possible negative effects of reusing the same async callback for C# socket BeginReceive?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I was wondering what the implications of using the same async callback as opposed to creating a new one each time BeginReceive is called. Can this produce exceptions, problems down the line, undesirable behavior?

For example:

```
client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                     new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

AsyncCallback asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback);
client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, asyncCallback, state);
```

Pretend the creation of the new async callback is not right next to BeginReceive and only called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the same one in the past and didn't experience any issues.  It shouldn't matter because it's just a delegate.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feed back. I guess I was worried about nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [`AsyncCallback` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=vs.110).aspx) and you will see that in the example they uses the same instance, so it should be fine.

If you think about it `AsyncCallback` is basically a `delegate` which is some kind of pointer to a method, the async operation needs to invoke something after completion and it really does not care if the delegate is reused or not, the delegate points to some code and this callback will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I accepted Michael's based on time since they were the same.